# Direct3DHook Send keyboard & mouse events to hooked application

Tags: c#, directx, easyhook

**I'm using Windows 10**

I've just been playing with [Direct3DHook](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook), which is built on [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/), and it works great. I would like to be able to use this tool to hook a Direct3D application. I'd then like to route keyboard and mouse events to the hooked application.

How can I do this? I believe that I can use things like [pInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) to simulate the events and route them to another application, but can I not do this using the Direct3DHook/EasyHook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ["Windows Input Simulator"](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)